# ANT: sort files in generated jar

Tags: java, sorting, ant

We use ANT to create jar files. In order to create 100% reliable builds (no matter on what machine they are generated), we want the files in the generated jar files to be sorted (so the used obfuscator produces the same result on each machine). The jar files (which then are sent to the obfuscator) are created using following code snippet:

```
<jar jarfile="my.jar" compress="false" duplicate="fail">
    <fileset dir="classes" includes="com/**"/>
    <!-- another fix -->
    <fileset dir="classes" includes="org/**"/>
</jar>
```

How can we ensure that the files in the jar file are sorted? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found a solution:

```
<local name="sortedFiles"/>
<pathconvert property="sortedFiles" pathsep="${line.separator}">
     <sort>
         <fileset dir="classes" includes="com/**"/>
     </sort>
     <sort>
         <fileset dir="classes" includes="org/**"/>
     </sort>
</pathconvert>
<jar jarfile="my.jar" compress="false" duplicate="fail">
    <filelist dir="classes" files="${sortedFiles}"/>
</jar>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to rely on your own sorting algoritm here. The Java spec doesn't mention any sorting logic. (not for files in a JAR, or JAR files in an EAR).
In your case, if you're building through ANT or Maven, at some point, the underlying OS will decide in what order the files are read from the filesystem and packaged in a JAR file.

If you really wan to have multiple machines doing builds, your best bet is to ensure that the machines you're using to perform the builds are based on the same hardware / OS, and using the same versions of the JDK,Ant,....

Another option (perhaps more feasable) is to delegate your builds to a dedicated build machine (where you also do the obfuscation), publish the artifacts in some kind of repository, and have your developers use those JAR files from that central repository.